# Why does Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() create direcotory in Cache folder

Tags: android, file, directory

When I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"applicationAsbid";` I expect to create a directory in device's external storage but it is created in Cache folder.
Why?
What happened and what should I do?

**UPDATE:**

This is my method:

```
root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        myDir = new File(root);
        myDir.mkdir();

 private void downloadDoc(ProgressBar progressBar, CircularImageView imageView, String name, String link, SendMessageViewModel messageData) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setTitle("در حال دانلود");
        request.setDescription("لطفا منتظر بمانید...");
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);



        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, root, name);

        final long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(id);
                Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    long downloadedBytes = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));

                    long totalBytes = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                    final int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                    final int percent = (int) ((downloadedBytes * 100) / totalBytes);
                    ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(percent);
                            if (percent == 100) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "دانلود با موفقیت انجام شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                timer.purge();
                                timer.cancel();
                                for (int item : downloadList) {
                                    if (Integer.parseInt(messageData.getId()) == item) {
                                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_doc3);
                                        imageView.setContentDescription("after");
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }


                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


            }
        }, 0, 100);
    }
```

At the end I should say this is not my own code and my colleague has written that. We check that and found nothing so I aske here.
We use Downloadmanager in another class and for download something else. That works fine but here it does not work.

**Second Update:**

I changed my code to this:

```
root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Dehkade/Chat1";
    myDir = new File(root);
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        if (!myDir.mkdir()) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext," ...sorry could not create directory...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

But it does not work too, in fact the Toast is executed. Also I use this code:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, null, name);
```

Instead of this code:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, root, name);
```

But nothing changes.

Comment: We dont believe that. Thatstatement does not create directories to begin with. Post your code and tell full path of directory.

Comment: @blackapps I updated my question and added the method

Comment: Start with only calling mkdir() when the directory does not exists yet. And stop if mkdir fails:  `if ( !myDir.exists() ) {if ( ! myDir.mkdir()) { Toast( ... sorry could not create directory...); return;} }` Please adapt your code here and report.
`

Comment: Further it is unclear why you try to create a directory in external storage which is also very wrong used in`request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, root, name); You cannot use a full path there. Only sub-directorie names.
`

Comment: Further: using DownloadManager you do not have to create directories at forehand as DownloadManager will do it for you.

Comment: Coming back on the first three lines of your code... That path is /storage/emulated/0 and is there. You cannot create it if it does not exist. Do away with there three lines and just supply a foldername for your request.

Comment: @blackapps When I changed the codes and added a Toast like the above one, Toast is executed and show the message

Comment: @blackapps If we can not create folder in root, so how does telegram or whatsapp create their own folders in root?

Comment: @blackapps I added my new code in a code block. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: You are calling mkdir three times. That makes no sense. And.. you could just copy the code from my comment... Sigh..

Comment: @blackapps At first I should say sorry for my childish question, because almost I never ever use file in my apps. Then I should ask you when I use that conditions, does application create a folder if does not exists? Because you didn't use myDir.mkdir() directly and use it only in a condition

Comment: Forget that extra code block. And replace your third code line (with mkdir) by the code i proposed.

Comment: @blackapps I believe I don't understand you, so I replace your code in a wrong place. before that I replace your code, application create the folder but now it doesn't even the folder. I replace the new code with the old one that you can check that. Thank you so much

Comment: Now remove the update stuff and that code block and copy the code from that codeblock to the first three lines of your code. So replace those first three lines. I asked you already a day ago to do so. And put File before root. Dont just start with a variable.

Comment: @blackapps May I move this discussion to chat that we can speak more about my problem?

Comment: No chatting. Read my second comment again. That was a day ago and you still did not change the code like i proposed.

Comment: @blackapps I changed that. Anyway I think I make you tired. Let it be. Thanks a lot for your guidance. I can not understand you and where should I change, so little by little you become exhausted and I don't want to do that. Thanks again